# Date values as Y-axis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts

I would like to have date values ax y-axis in highcharts column chart.
An example can be seen here: http://i39.tinypic.com/27zvwgm.png
I know how to generate charts with integer ax y-axis, but I don't know how to use dates as y-axis.

I would appreciate your help,
Thanks

Comment: That's really ... untraditional. Why?

Comment: The customer wants such chart, I don't know the use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [type](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.type) as datetime, and use correct value in points (like timestamp).